# How to make typeconverter work with list of custom class that contains list?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, detection, typeconverter

The Entity class. I want to fetch items as camera detector detects objects. What kind of typeconverter would take list of items class, confidence etc. ?

```
@Entity(tableName = "Objects_table")
data class Objects(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "object_id")
        var id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "object_name")
        var name: DetectionResult?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "detected_time")
        var time: Result?)
```

The Results class that I want to fetch

```
data class Result(
        val id: Int,
        val title: String,
        val confidence: Float,
        val location: RectF
) {
    val text: String by lazy {
        "$id:$title[${"%.2f".format(confidence)}]"
    }
}
```

The ViewModel class:

```
class ObjectViewModel(private val repository: ObjectRepository) : ViewModel(), Observable {

    val objects = repository.objects
    private var objectDetected: ObjectDetectorAnalyzer? = null

    fun saver(){
        val name = objectDetected?.nobjects?.get(0)
        val conf = objectDetected?.nobjects?.get(1)

    }
```

The class from where I reference list of objects that lively changes:

```
class ObjectDetectorAnalyzer(
        private val context: Context,
        private val config: Config,
        private val onDetectionResult: (Result) -> Unit
): ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private var inputArray = IntArray(config.inputSize * config.inputSize)

    val nobjects = detect(inputArray)
     
    private fun detect(inputArray: IntArray): List<DetectionResult> {
        var detector = objectDetector
        if (detector == null) {
            detector = ObjectDetector(
                    assetManager = context.assets,
                    isModelQuantized = config.isQuantized,
                    inputSize = config.inputSize,
                    labelFilename = config.labelsFile,
                    modelFilename = config.modelFile,
                    numDetections = config.numDetection,
                    minimumConfidence = config.minimumConfidence,
                    numThreads = 1,
                    useNnapi = false
            )
            objectDetector = detector
        }

        return detector.detect(inputArray)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This example might help you.
I have one Animal entity and have its Breed List

```
@Entity(tableName = "Animal")
public class Animal {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long pid;
    
    @TypeConverters(BreedConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "breed")
    private ArrayList<Breed> breedArrayList;    
}
```

I have annotation with @TypeConverters pointing to BreedConverter.class

```
class BreedConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toBreedList(data: String): ArrayList<Breed> {
        val listType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Breed>>() {}.type
        return GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(data, listType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toBreedString(breed:  ArrayList<Breed>): String {
        return GsonBuilder().create().toJson(breed)
    }
}
```

Its working fine for my case. You can try this way. TypeConverter would convert the list to string while persisting and will convert back to list from string when you access this object using getters.